# Trying to scrape all 'a' text from within specific 'td's using python and bs4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/fixtures/ to extract the text contained in the 'a' tag, specifically within the table with class, "table-main", then for each row within that.  The first td contains text with the two team names, with a td class, "h-text-left".  Unsure if the issue is with my loop or not, but the error message I am getting seems like I am using bs4 incorrectly on my final line in the loop.

I can scrape each tr within the table with class, "table-main", then furthermore, each td with class, "h-text-left".  I am hitting a deadend though when trying to extract the 'a' elements alone, not even the 'a' text.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':
           'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get('https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/fixtures/', headers=headers)

c = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c)

fixture_table = soup.find('table', attrs = {'class': 'table-main'})

for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    match_tds = tr.find_all('td', attrs = {'class': 'h-text-left'})
    matches = match_tds.find_all('a')
```

Last line when I am trying to find all of the 'a' tags trips the following error:

```
...     matches = match_tds.find_all('a')
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Glypt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1884, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
>>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce that down to a much faster selector method using a single class. All the links have the same class name so you can pass that to `select`, inside a list comprehension, to give you all the links.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/fixtures/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
matches = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.in-match')]
```

---

Odds

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/fixtures/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
odds = [item['data-odd'] for item in soup.select('.table-main__odds [data-odd]')]
print(odds)
```

Comment: I am trying this approach now, but what I am actually trying to do is extract the link text, not the href attribute.   I tried to modify your example in order to extract the odds text, but I am not getting any output when printing it, i.e. []

<td class="table-main__odds" data-oid="33jkrxv464x0x7k7pm">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="my_selections_click('1x2', 'soccer', 'action=3&amp;matchid=tKLzuv9M&amp;outcomeid=33jkrxv464x0x7k7pm&amp;otheroutcomes=33jkrxv498x0x0,33jkrxv464x0x7k7pn');" title="Add to My Selections">2.08
</a>
</td>

Comment: So sorry, these links do not have a class of '.in-match', or rather any class at all.  I tried to parse out the 'title' attribute, though, which seems to always be 'Add to My Selections'.   I am getting no output though when trying to print the matches list after this, though.

Comment: Apologies for the terrible formatting, but for the example a element I provided above, I am looking to extract the text, "2.08" from the a element.

Comment: You would change to item.text for item in

Comment: matches = [item.text for item in soup.select('.in-match')]

odds = [item.text for item in soup.select('Add to My Selections')]

The first works as you described, however, the second does not work when I am trying to target the a elements' title attribute.  Still printing out []

Comment: Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

`match_tds` is a list, not single element  - you get it with `tr.find_all(...)` - so you have to use `for` loop to run another `find_all()`

```
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    match_tds = tr.find_all('td', attrs = {'class': 'h-text-left'})
    for item in match_tds:
        matches = item.find_all('a')
        for a in matches:
            print(a['href'])
```

If you use `find()` to get first element then you can use with another `find()` or `find_all()`

```
soup.find(...).find(...).find_all(...)
```

but you can't use `find()` or `find_all()` after `find_all()`

```
# ERROR
soup.find_all(...).find_all(...) 

# ERROR
soup.find_all(...).find(...)
```

Comment: Thank you, got exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the built in functionality to find nested structures. You can specify a `.css` class with `'.class_name'` and find nested structures with ''first selector' > 'second selector'` (or even more selectors). Together this would look like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.session()
s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'
res = s.get('https://www.betexplorer.com/soccer/england/premier-league/fixtures/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

matches = soup.select('.table-main  tr  td  a')
for match in matches:
    print(match.getText())
```

The line `matches = soup.select('.table-main  tr  td  a')` will select all `a` elements that are within a `td` element that are within `tr` element that are within a `class=table-main` element. Additionally you can use `matches = soup.select('td > a')` (the `>` operator) to specify that the `a` element is *directly* within an `td` element. I imagine this could potentially greatly simplify your code!

Note I could not test this on my machine as the SSL certificate could not be confirmed and raised `requests.exceptions.SSLError`

Answer (score 0):

To get the text, try:

```
for td in soup.findAll('td', attrs = {'class': 'h-text-left'}):
    print(td.findAll('a')[0].text)
```